# How to create async/await code in C++?

Tags: c++, asynchronous, lambda, async-await, rpc

I'm using remote RPC of my network service and I don't want to create any delegates in my code with binding an other things. I want to wrote pseudo-asynchroused code. Something like this:

```
 await (MyServer->RemoteMethod(parameter_1, parameter_2), 
      [=] (int32 return_value_1, int32 return_value_2) {
           UE_LOG(MyLog, Log, TEXT("RemoteMethod called with result %i %i"), return_value_1, return_value_2);
      });
```

I'm not too strong in functional programming of latest C++ versions.
But I know there is things like `std::function`. Can this help me?

Also I need that code must be cross-platform.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're describing is not `async`-`await`, with that, you would be able to write:

```
std::pair<int32, int32> return_values = await MyServer->RemoteMethod(parameter_1, parameter_2);
UE_LOG(MyLog, Log, TEXT("RemoteMethod called with result %i %i"), return_values.first, return_values.second);
```

I believe this feature is planned to be in some future version of C++.

What you're describing is a *continuation* and you can use [`boost::future`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html#thread.synchronization.futures.then) for that:

```
boost::future<std::pair<int32, int32>> return_values_future = MyServer->RemoteMethod(parameter_1, parameter_2);
return_values_future.then([=](boost::future<std::pair<int32, int32>> fut) {
    UE_LOG(MyLog, Log, TEXT("RemoteMethod called with result %i %i"), fut.get().first, fut.get().second);
});
```

Comment: 'await' is a part of a pending proposal from MS for C++ coroutines - looks like some of it may be usable in some versions of Visual Studio https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_fu0gx-xseY for a presentation on it from last year's cppcon.